# Word to describe a mathematical variable that repeats, like an angle or time

Tags: terminology, mathematics

In mathematics a variable can be said to be *constrained* if it must lie within certain bounds, for example:

```
0 < x < 1  (the variable x is constrained: it lies between zero and one)
```

However some kinds of variables (such as an angle, or time of day) can be constrained with an additional property that their values form a closed loop: if I increase the value past the upper bound it reappears at the lower bound. For example:

```
11 o'clock + 2hours = 1 o'clock
```

Is there an adjective or name to describe this kind of 'circular' variable?

Comment: @Bogdan: I guess you might know better than I would since I'm not a frequent contributor to math.SE, but by analogy, if this came up on the physics site, where I'm a moderator, there's a chance it would be considered off topic since it's arguably about language, not physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've described is referred to as "wrapping" and a variable that wraps around is called a *wrapped variable*.

As jimreed rightly points out, the cause of wrapping is due to modular arithmetic and it is very uncommon to explicitly mention that a variable is "wrapped" because it is assumed to be understood. The only time I've seen mathematical/scientific articles use the term wrapped variable is when they also talk about "unwrapping" the variable. So in your clock example, you would add 12 after each time it completes a full circle to get an unwrapped variable.

I don't have a wiki link to the definition (because, as I said, it's not used commonly). However, the article on [wrapped distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_distribution) uses the term wrapped variable.

Answer (score 7):

You could use *periodic* if the repetition follows any kind of function.

Comment: "Periodic" is the first thing that comes to my mind (though I come from a physics perspective, not pure math).

Comment: I have extensive classroom mathematics experience and `periodic` is the term we almost always used for a function that repeats.  The "length" of each repetition is called the `period` of the function.

Comment: Yeah, its periodic.  See complex [phasors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) for the basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

You might say that the variable is [cyclic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cyclic) although that term more correctly applies to the values the variable can have than the variable itself.

Instead of talking about the variable, I would say that the operations on that variable use [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: it is not "cyclic", since Z (the set of integers) is cyclic but unbounded. Also, it is not "modular arithmetic" because time is a continuous variable, unless we restrict to the whole hours: 0,1,...,24.

Answer (score 0):

This is a math question.

The answer is *yes*, periodicity isn't confined to being in one dimension.

[Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) sums up the idea of the sum e^{jt} = cos(t) + jsin(t) travelling in a circle in the complex plane as t goes from 0 to 2pi.  See also [phasors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor).

Answer (score 0):

Another word for this type of variable is **modular**.

> In mathematics, modular arithmetic is a system of arithmetic for
>   integers, where numbers "wrap around" upon reaching a certain
>   value—the modulus. The modern approach to modular arithmetic was
>   developed by Carl Friedrich Gauss in his book Disquisitiones
>   Arithmeticae, published in 1801.
>
> A familiar use of modular arithmetic is in the 12-hour clock, in which
>   the day is divided into two 12-hour periods. If the time is 7:00 now,
>   then 8 hours later it will be 3:00. Usual addition would suggest that
>   the later time should be 7+8=15, but this is not the answer because
>   clock time "wraps around" every 12 hours; in 12-hour time, there is no
>   "15 o'clock". Likewise, if the clock starts at 12:00 (noon) and 21
>   hours elapse, then the time will be 9:00 the next day, rather than
>   33:00. Because the hour number starts over after it reaches 12, this
>   is arithmetic modulo 12. According to the definition below, 12 is
>   congruent not only to 12 itself, but also to 0, so the time called
>   "12:00" could also be called "0:00", since 12 is congruent to 0 modulo
>   12.

([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic))

You can also refer, as suggested, to a "modular variable."